# MySQL UPDATE with JOINS using MAX

Tags: mysql

I'm no MySQL guru.
I'm trying to `update` a table `clients.converted` from `projects.last_update` column.

**DATETIME**: `clients.converted` (new column as of now).

**DATETIME**: `projects.last_update`.

**BOOLEAN**: `projects.converted`.

For each client's project, there is the possibility to ***end*** the project with a `prospect-to-client` *conversion*, if so, `(boolean) projects.converted` will me `TRUE`.

What I want is to do an `UPDATE` statement on `clients` to fill `clients.converted` from `MAX(projects.last_update)` `WHERE` project's `projects.converted = true`.

So far I have tried a couple of queries, but this one grasps the idea in a less-confusing way:

```
UPDATE clients AS `Client`
INNER JOIN projects AS `Project` ON Project.client_id = Client.id
SET Client.converted = MAX(Project.last_update)
WHERE Project.converted = TRUE;
```

But it's not working (because I can't use `MAX` function directly on assignment) and I've run out of ideas on how to do an `UPDATE` with `JOINS` using the `MAX` function applied to a `DATETIME` column.

> I did a `SELECT` statement to gather the information I need first and
>   it works like a charm:

```
SELECT Client.id,  count(*), MAX(Project.last_update)  FROM projects AS `Project`
LEFT JOIN clients AS `Client` ON Client.id = Project.client_id
WHERE Project.converted = TRUE
GROUP BY Client.id;
```

Any help is very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX is an aggregate function, which means it cannot (or rather, generally should not) be used without a GROUP BY; you'll need to use a subquery.

```
UPDATE clients AS `Client`
INNER JOIN (SELECT client_id, MAX(last_update) AS max_lu 
            FROM projects 
            WHERE converted = TRUE
            GROUP BY client_id
) AS `Project` ON Project.client_id = Client.id
SET Client.converted = Project.max_lu
;
```

Comment: I'm updating my database right now, but as soon as It's done, I'll try what you posted, thanks! :)